# HtmlAgilityPack parsing table

Tags: c#

I've been having some difficulty finding an efficient way to parse this html file using HtmlAgilityPack. I can read all of the contents but the way I go about doing so is very sloppy and I was hoping to get some suggestions or even some copy pasta if I dare ask so that I can manage to read the data efficiently.

```
    private void ParsePage(string html)
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        if (doc.DocumentNode != null)
        {
            var gameTypes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='lifetime_stats_header']");

            if (gameTypes != null) {
                foreach (var gt in gameTypes)
                {
                    if (gt != null && gt.InnerText != null && this.rtbHtmlReceived != null)
                    {
                        this.rtbHtmlReceived.AppendText("Played type : " + gt.InnerText.ToString().Replace(" ", "") + "\n");
                        this.rtbHtmlReceived.AppendText(
                            "dSibSib : " + gt.NextSibling.NextSibling.InnerText.Replace(" ", "") + "\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm printing out currently using what I have,

> ```
> Wins885
> Kills3,805
> Assists4,140
> MinionKills92,536
> NeutralMinionKills16,739
> TurretsDestroyed741
> ```

which come from a table that looks like

```
                        <tbody>
                        <tr><td class="lifetime_stats_key">Wins</td><td class="lifetime_stats_val">885</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="lifetime_stats_key">Kills</td><td class="lifetime_stats_val">3,805</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="lifetime_stats_key">Assists</td><td class="lifetime_stats_val">4,140</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="lifetime_stats_key">Minion Kills</td><td class="lifetime_stats_val">92,536</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="lifetime_stats_key">Neutral Minion Kills</td><td class="lifetime_stats_val">16,739</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="lifetime_stats_key">Turrets Destroyed</td><td class="lifetime_stats_val">741</td></tr>
                        </tbody>
```

Any suggestions or pointers on how to loops through the lifetime_stats_val and keys would be great! can't figure it out :S 
I'll keep researching but i'd love you for any answers you may have :P

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out,

```
        foreach (var gt in gameTypes.Where(gt => gt != null && gt.InnerText != null && this.rtbHtmlReceived != null))
        {
            var cells = gt.NextSibling.NextSibling.ChildNodes.Descendants("tr");
            foreach (var item in cells)
            {
                rtbHtmlReceived.AppendText("Type: " + item.FirstChild.InnerText + ": ");
                rtbHtmlReceived.AppendText("Value: " + item.LastChild.InnerText + "\n");
            }
        }
```